# error NG8002: Can't bind to 'state' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a trouble with tslint I think but not sure. I'm doing a project in Angular 9 and for the form, everytime I save the file, the material component go to lowercase ( matInput => matinput).

Here is my app component

```
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    
  ],
  imports: [
    MatTableModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatIconModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
                            <input matinput placeholder="identifiant" required name="identifiant" [(ngModel)]="model.identifiant" #identifiant="ngModel">
                            <mat-error *ngIf="identifiant.invalid">Login is required</mat-error>
                            <mat-icon matsuffix>email</mat-icon>
                        </mat-form-field>
```

And the message code is

```
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'state' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
```

Everytime I change matInput or any other material class, it's change for lowercase. Anyone already got this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

import FormsModule in your app.module file

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

**add it in imports array**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from the plugins in vscode. I used some for twig synthaxe and the trouble came from that.